# how to disable server directory listing?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, .htaccess

The problem is that I have an index.html and using angularjs I call in query/ directory .php files for example connection.php (that connect to the database mysql), users.php (number of users registered to my website) the problem is that if someone try to write www.mywebsite.com/query/ can see the list of the queries present into my database, is there any method to block them? I tried to edit .htaccess file changing the path but writing the changed path there is the same problem.

Comment: *write www.mywebsite.com/query/ can see the list of the queries* then you did something absolute wrong :( ..  why did't you echo querys? why are those files in document_root dir?

Comment: @donald123 where i need to put my queries?

Comment: @donald123 for example this is one of a websites that i build, i am absolutly noob i think http://letmebep.com/query/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess file

Options -Indexes

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me, it work more than perfect :)

Comment: We are here to help :D

Comment: But you should change question name to "how to disable server directory listing"

Answer (score 0):

For Angular, you my disable the directories by adding the below configuration on nginx.conf file under src\nginx\conf\includes folder. This will restrict all the directories and subdirectories being listed.

```
location{
   autoindex off;
}
```